# Run multiple containers on same docker network localhost

Tags: docker

I want to connect from my app to mongodb on localhost, so they need to have same localhost address.

So the question is: **Can two containers share they localhost, or for each container the localhost ip must be different?**

I'm doing this for test environment purposes, so I don't want in-memory database, changed mongo uri or any different solution. I just want to connect from A to B by localhost.

To run my network and containers i type:

```
docker network create --driver bridge isolated_nw
docker run --name mongodb -d -p 27017:27017 --network=isolated_nw mongo:3.4.2
docker run --name roomate-profiles --network=isolated_nw -d -p 8080:8080 sovas/roomate-profiles
```

My custom docker network:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "isolated_nw",
        "Id": "3efd6831784c2a8c9e9ea345144fcc6b9180e70c0e1b4b5d1a72219051b24e67",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1/16"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Containers": {
            "57d4e2fb1f0c8d776329fd6ce82e5905df00e261ab6923595578dcb35913b03e": {
                "Name": "roomate-profiles",
                "EndpointID": "5a8158dc1aba6958218d1cca3c98ca911ab2cfa73be839ceece2e7819b244c91",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "8fa815735d7ebb77434f8abf11e58f18faeb5d67e2743903d81f4600bd558c35": {
                "Name": "mongodb",
                "EndpointID": "7b7a7ed1ad08bbe381fb6d66c6e9fea66ee9b7c581f530bdf4d82f0741bff04b",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

application.properties

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/admin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localhost` won't work since it refers to the roomate-profiles container. But you can do

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://mongodb:27017/admin
```

since both containers are connected to the same network. There is also no need to map the mongodb port to the host (unless you need it for something else).